# make a dynamic input range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make "css3 animation website" and I want the user to be able to control the value by " range input" . 
I want to make the result that in the range input appear in "value" but in jQuery not javascript

[image: this img show what I'm asking for]

Comment: What are you having problems with here? Could you share a [mcve] of how you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for an `input` event on the range input, and then set the HTML of the value of the range by using `$('#val').html($(this).val())`

See example below:

```js
$('input[type="range"]').on('input', function() {
  $('#val').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" />
<p>Value: <span id="val">50</span>
```